# Nhibernate Linq 3 In Clause

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

It seems that a In clause is not working properly with Linq 3.0 (trunk)

I tried following:

```
var l = session.Query<MyClass>.Where(p => searchGroups.Contains(p.ID)).Select(r=>r);
```

I get an exception that says that

```
the Binary operator for \"System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Int32]\" and \"System.Int32 is not defined
```

With Linq 1.0 it works properly

```
var l = session.Linq<MyClass>.Where(p => searchGroups.Contains(p.ID)).Select(r=>r);
```

Should I use something different with the new Linq version or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug.

If you want to use NHibernate.Linq, **I suggest you to upgrade to NHibernate 3.2**, it works like a charm.

The NHibernate 3.0 LINQ provider is a step back comparted with the previous versions...